# autocomplete and bootstrap combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have bootstrap combobox where on autocomplete change I want to select value, problem is that this works only when I double click filtered result inside combo, if I click only once I'm getting myselection variable empty.

```
$('#MyComboId').on('change', function () {
     var myselection = $(this).find("option:selected").val();          
  });    
});
```

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: Does this https://jsfiddle.net/neceegbv/5/ fit your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understand you use `bootstrap-combobox` ([Link](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox)).

I found setter code:

```
select: function () {
  var val = this.$menu.find('.active').attr('data-value');
  this.$element.val(this.updater(val)).trigger('change');
  this.$target.val(this.map[val]).trigger('change');
  this.$source.val(this.map[val]).trigger('change');
  this.$container.addClass('combobox-selected');
  this.selected = true;
  return this.hide();
}
```

**Update:**

When user clicks on item from dropdownlist, `change` event will fire, which is incorrect. I.e. input will be cleaned, after that it will be filled with correct value.

```
var el = $('.combobox').combobox();

el.on('change', function(e){
 if($(this).data('combobox').$element.val() == ''){
   console.log('Its triggered incorrectly');
   return false;
 }

 var dic = $(this).data('combobox').map,
    val = $(this).val(),
  clean = true;

 for(var i in dic){
   if(!dic.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
   if(dic[i] == val){
     console.log(dic[i], i); // dic[i] = value, i = label
     clean = false;
     break;
   }
 }

 if(clean)
   console.log('Input was cleared');
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/neceegbv/9/)

Comment: Actually this jsfiddle link you provide is actually perfect example of the I problem I'm experiencing. You see, when you select from the combo NewYork it works fine, but if you type New and then try to select New York from the menu it doesn't work.